# Can I change the frontend of my app to Angular after it's already finished?

Tags: angular, express, frontend

So I have made a simple CRUD application using NODE, Express and Mongoose on a local machine. This is the [link](https://github.com/Squadcore/Mean-Blog) on GitHub.

This was part of a task in my education before we started learning Angular. Now, we have a new assignment which is basically the same thing but with one new requirement - **to be built upon Angular framework using TypeScript**.

I am not familiar with Angular, so I had an idea to just replace

```
<h4> <%= blogpost.title %> </h4>
<p>  <%= blogpost.content %> </p>
<p>Author: <%= blogpost.author.username %></p>
<p>Posted: <%= blogpost.created.toTimeString() %> </p>
```

With something like

```
<h4>{{blogpost.title}}</h4>
<p>  {{blogpost.content}} </p>
<p>Author: {{blogpost.author.username}}</p>
<p>Posted: {{blogpost.created.toTimeString()}} </p>
```

Just for the sake of this task.

My question is, can I do this quickly without changing much in my app or should I learn Angular and start over?

Comment: It's kind of based on opinion. Personally, I would suggest learning the basics. That way, if you need to debug any issues, you know what's going on. Also, Angular is rendered client-side, so you need to figure out how you're going to pass those values (blogpost etc) to the client

Comment: it is quite easy to do it with angular. you can read the documentation with the examples and without going too deeply in the details you can build this. :)

Comment: you will need few REST APIs to send the information to the client

Comment: He says he already has express set up, he should be fine.